# button click delete dom hide element preventing me to show it

Tags: javascript, ajax, get

I'm doing a simple thing but I do not understand why it occurs the following problem: when I enter a value in the form and click the button to execute the function the 'loading' the element disappears and can not be shown.

The Javascript is the following:

```
<div>
    <input id="magLog" name="magLog" type="text" style="width: 500px;"/>
    <button id="StartITSMcheck">Check</button>
</div>
<div>
    <div id="logContainer" class="filtersUNoBorder" style="padding-left: 8px; height:auto">
        <div id="loading" class="clear loading">
                Caricamento in corso...</div>
        <!--Add text after check-->
    </div>
</div>    
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#loading").hide();
    });
    $("#StartITSMcheck").click(function () {
        if ($("#magLog").val() != "" && $("#magLog").val() != undefined) {
            $('#loading').show();  // show the loading message.
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '<%= Url.Action("StartITSMcheck", "Integration") %>',
                async: false,
                data: { "magLog": $("#magLog").val() },
                datatype: "html",
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#logContainer").html(result);
                    $('#loading').hide(); // hide the loading message
                },
                error: function (req, status, error) {
                    if (req.responseText.indexOf('12017') != -1) {
                        alert("CATCH: Status: " + status + " Error " + req.responseText);
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("Error getting data.com -> Req.responseText: " + req.responseText + "Req.status: " + req.status + "  status: " + status + " error: " + error);
                    }
                }
            });
        } else $("#logContainer").html("<p>Gentilmente inserire un magazzino logico</p>");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: may be your function is going into the error call back. hide loading in the error call back as well.

Comment: Making synchronous calls is a bad idea. That also can be a reason why the loading graphic does not show up.

Comment: @Deep I have to put the hide even in error but it is not inherent in the display problem.

Comment: @epascarello You are right!! removing the synchronicity correctly displays the loading. You have an explanation for this? because I expect that the next steps to get synchronous not avviassero before its completion. (Probably due to the fact that the browser is running in parallel with the operations in the function to optimize)

Comment: This is the explanation (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/): Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request is active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#logContainer").html(result);
```

This is probably the cause of the problem. You're replacing everything inside the div with your response, that includes your loading element. Try placing it outside the div, like this:

```
<div id="logContainer" class="filtersUNoBorder" style="padding-left: 8px; height:auto">
    <!--Add text after check-->
</div>
<div id="loading" class="clear loading">Caricamento in corso...</div>
```

Comment: I excluded this possibility because the dom element disappeared immediately after the click. I also tried the way you suggest, and in fact the dom element does not disappear, but the problem remains: when I press the button, the loading animation is not shown during the pending status of the request.

Comment: Try showing the loading element using the `beforeSend` option in the AJAX call.
Example: `$.ajax({ 
beforeSend: function () { $('#loading').show() } 
}`

Comment: like before :( . if I use the debug I see that the steps are performed correctly; but if I remove the breakpoint and press the button I do not sell the loading, but only the key which remains "clicked" for a few seconds.